# jQuery validator: custom validation not working in Symfony2

Tags: jquery, symfony, twig, jquery-validate

I am trying to implement jquery validation in my symfony2 project.If i apply `class="required "` in a text field, the validation works fine but when try to apply custom validation like

```
$("#checkoutForm").validate({  
    rules: {
        checkout_name: {
            required:true
        } 
    }
});
```

Comment: Does your Custom validation methods accepts an object(`{}`)? Can you post the code of the custom method?

Comment: Did you read the source and specially the input name ? Symfony prefixes  fields with the name of the form, perhaps the solution (myform_checkout_name) ?

Comment: @dshai i have edited the code.This is exactly the code that i am using excrpt the `$(document).ready line which is obvious

Comment: @Shaun As commented by Sybio Have you also verified the page source for the input's _name_ is it same as the one you're using in your validation code?

Comment: input name is `checkout[name]` but it gives error like `missing operator after id` thats y i m using by ID

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
$("#checkoutForm").validate({  
    rules: {
        'checkout[name]': {
            required:true
        } 
    }
});
```